# Show that any uniformly convergent sequence of bounded functions is uniformly bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

i want to show my proof of this exercise and please if someone want review and fix my proof I will be very grateful.

> **Theorem:** Prove that any uniformly convergent sequence of bounded
>   functions is uniformly bounded
>
> **Proof:** Let $\epsilon>0$, $\left\{ f_{n}\right\}$ a sequence defined in $A\subset R$ and $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
>
> As $\left\{ f_{n}\right\}$ is uniformly convergent then exist
>   $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq N$ then
>   $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<1$ for all $x\in A$ (*)
>
> Otherwise,
>
> For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ exists $M_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $|f_{n}(x)|<M_{n}$ for all $x\in A$
>
> Then, if $n\geq N$ and for (*) we have:
>
> $|f(x)|=|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(x)+f(x)|\leq|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|+|f_{n}(x)|<1+M_{n}$
>
> Let $C=\max\{M_{1},...,M_{n},M_{n}+1\}$ then
>
> $|f(x)|<C$
>
> In consequence,
>
> $f(x)$ is uniformly bounded.

Comment: It looks like you should prove that there is a constant $C$ satisfying$|f_n(x)| \le C$ for all $x \in A$ and all $n \in \mathbb N$.